# Changing tooltip text for CToolBar programmatically

Tags: mfc

I'm maintaining an MFC application with a toolbar. Now I need to programmatically change the text in the tooltips that are shown when you hoover over the toolbar buttons:

[image: Toolbar]

MFC takes this text (here "About") from the from the string table in the resources where the string ID has the same number as the command ID, (here ID_APP_ABOUT).

But I just need to change these texts programmatically (e.g "My About" instead of "About").

Comment: If the text will change dynamically during the session then you may need to handle `TTN_NEEDTEXT` and provide the text whenever the tooltip is about to be displayed.

Comment: I didn't realize you want to change it programatically. Maybe just trying to change string resource text programatically..haven't tried this but maybe it will work.